# Find number of real people in a discord server [discord.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I am trying to have my bot see the number of real people that are in the servers that my bot is in and the bot keeps coming back with wrong values
here is my code:

```
let realMembers = 0;

for (const guild of client.guilds.cache) {
      realMembers += await guild[1].members.cache.filter((m) => !m.user.bot).size;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for... of` works similarly to the `.forEach()` function. It loops through an entire array using a set **parameter** that represents the current element used.

Judging by your code, let's set the values:

- client.guilds.cache = Your **array** (Technically a Collection, although it works just as well) of guild objects.
- guild = Your element **parameter**.

Now, your `guild` parameter represents an object, but not the actual array of guilds, meaning we cannot use `guild[1]` as it does not return an object itself, and it obviously does not hold a `members` property.

Please also keep in mind `.size` returns a Number, not a promise, therefore there is no reason to await it.

From here I am not exactly getting what you're trying to do, if I'm being honest. Assuming that you're trying to get the total amount of users in the guilds your client is in, the following code should fix it:

```
let realMembers = 0;

for (const guild of client.guilds.cache) {
      realMembers += guild.members.cache.filter((m) => !m.user.bot).size;
}

console.log(realMembers)
```

Comment: I now get the error cannot read property 'cache' of undefined